# Set Target Audience by specific view of SharePoint List using Modern Experience

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, web-parts

In Classic Experience, there’s an “Edit Page” on settings where I can access WebParts and set target audience per specific view of SharePoint List, however, this is not possible on Modern Experience. Are there any ways where I can restrict those so other group user cannot open specific views?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in Classic experience, there are currently only partial modern web parts which support audience targeting in SharePoint Online. Please take a reference to thi article: [Target content to a specific audience on a SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-content-to-a-specific-audience-on-a-sharepoint-site-68113d1b-be99-4d4c-a61c-73b087f48a81).

Comment: I tried your reference but it’s not working or perhaps I’m doing it wrong. Other group users can still access specific views.

Comment: Maybe you need to wait for a while before it takes effect.